# Port is closed even I opened it

Tags: c#, portforwarding

I need help with solving my problem.
I use Comtrend VR 302e.
I have setted up port forwarding like this.
But when I open the online port checker or telnet, it tells me that my port is closed. Why?

[Here is the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJGbB.jpg)

Codes:

Server

```
    static byte[] data;  // 1
    static Socket socket; // 1

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3459));

            socket.Listen(10);
            Socket acceptData = socket.Accept();
            data = new byte[acceptData.SendBufferSize];
            int j = acceptData.Receive(data);
            byte[] adata = new byte[j];
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                adata[i] = data[i];
            }
            string dat = Encoding.Default.GetString(adata);
            Console.WriteLine(dat);
        }

    }
```

Client here

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
try // 1
{
    s.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), 3459); // 2
    string q = "It works";                 // 3
    byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(q);    // 3
    s.Send(data);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: We want see the complete (but short) code here, not on an external site.

Comment: Edited and added code